# Can I reset my dev Org?

Tags: force.com, metadata, custom-object

I'm using my dev org for testing proposes and It's taking my many time to delete objects, data, rules and so on.

It is possible to reset this account to original state?

Comment: The easiest 'wipe' is to refresh the sandbox from Production.

Comment: Your best option in a dev org is what Josh suggested. If it's too much work I'd rather just create a new org; they are free :)

Comment: If you create a new DE you can still use the same username if you change the old DE user's username first. I rename the old DE username something like username@org.com.old01 and then always keep my current DE having the same base username like username@org.com.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might look at using the Force.com Migration Tool to "undeploy" via destructiveChanges.xml, see more information here:

http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/General-Development/Deleting-using-the-migration-tool/td-p/246145

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to - you can just sign up for a new Developer Edition account. You don't need to use the email address as the user name - for example, I have a user name of leon@customer.demo with the email address of leon@domain.com.  Don't forget that when you *initially* sign up with an email address that has to be your username - you can change it subsequently however.

Notwithstanding that, using a gmail account to manage multiple accounts is quite cool - gmail has a feature that you can put +anything after the name and it treats it as the same address - eg if my email address is leon@gmail.com, I can send emails to leon+customer@gmail.com and they will go to the right address. Makes it easy to manage multiple logins.

Comment: I found that after signing up for a couple of different developer accounts using different emails, they all suddenly got disabled. Not sure why, but perhaps Salesforce didn't like me having several dev accounts ....